# How to get div elements without accessing DOM in React?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

In my react app, I am trying to fetch the  elements using document.getElementByID("id_of_div") to write to the UI using innerHTML as shown in the code below. I am using react and interacting with the DOM directly, which isn't the React way of doing things. Please suggest how I can change this approach and write my data, stored as object to the UI in react. 
Thanks in Advance.

```
    var uname = this.state.appuser;
    axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var display_city = response.data.data.request[0].query;
        var Date1 = response.data.data.weather[0].date;
        var windSpeed = response.data.data.current_condition[0].windspeedKmph;
        var maxTempC = response.data.data.weather[0].maxtempC;
        var minTempC = response.data.data.weather[0].mintempC;
        var humidity = response.data.data.current_condition[0].humidity;
        var visibility1 = response.data.data.current_condition[0].visibility;
        var myobj = {
            welcome_user: uname,
            disp_city: display_city,
            date: Date1,
            wind_speed: windSpeed,
            maxtempC: maxTempC,
            mintempC: minTempC,
            humid: humidity,
            visibility: visibility1
        }
        console.log(myobj);
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "Welcome " + myobj.welcome_user;
        document.getElementById("cityHolder").innerHTML = myobj.disp_city;
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = myobj.date;
        document.getElementById("windspeed").innerHTML = myobj.wind_speed + " kmph";
        document.getElementById("maxtemp").innerHTML = myobj.maxtempC + "  C";
        document.getElementById("mintemp").innerHTML = myobj.mintempC + "  C";
        document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = myobj.humid + " %";
        document.getElementById("visibility").innerHTML = myobj.visibility + "%";

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

},
```

I do not want to access the inner  elements defined in another component by document.getElementById("divid")
What is the react way of pushing my data from myobj object to the UI?

Answer (score 0):

I've only just started learning react but I think from reading the documentation you can use the below.

```
// tutorial1.js
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

[Documentation Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#your-first-component)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use refs in react for this. For that first you have to create a ref.

Creating a ref

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
```

Then you can easily access your div element and change anything using..

```
 const node = this.myRef.current;
 node.innerHTML = "Enter text you want"
```